# UrlFetchApp fetch post to Zoho Creator API, Zoho needs the session to be closed

Tags: google-apps-script, zoho

Am using UrlFetchApp fetch to post to Zoho Creator's API.

I obtain the correct response however, after the post is completed the Zoho Creator platform displays the session as active.

This is not desirable as Zoho will only allow a limited number of active sessions before their API stops responding to posts.

Does anyone have any experience or suggestions on how to implement a "close" session after using UrlFetchApp.

Thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged with google-app-engine?  UrlFetchApp is not part of App Engine.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this in the Zoho API forums:

> **Logout/Close a Ticket**:
> You can close/clear/logout/invalidate
>   a particular API ticket after you have completed the operation. An
>   HTTPS POST request sent to Zoho Accounts to close the API ticket will
>   look like the one below:
> <form method="POST"
>   action="https://accounts.zoho.com/logout"
>   target="_self">
> <input type="hidden"
>   name="ticket"
>   value="<ticket_value>">
> <input
>   type="hidden" name="FROM_AGENT"
>   value="true">
> </form>
>  Note: The parameters
>   are case-sensitive.

Please check if this is useful to you: https://forums.zoho.com/topic/attn-zoho-api-developers-important-data-api-update-limit-concurrent-api-sessions-to-20-use-https-post-for-generating-tickets

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at Zoho's API and what they require for this.  This is not a UrlFetchApp related issue.